# Yui chart in EXTJS4 MVC Panel

Tags: javascript, extjs, yui

I am Working on EXTJS4 MVC Portal,
& I want to display YUI chart in portletpanel.
I dont know how to configure YUI chart.

Please HELP.....

Thanks

Comment: Try to make your question more concrete. What exactly have you tried? Maybe an example/code? How fare have you gotten? Error? I doubt you will get an answer to your question like this, because it is very hard to figure out what you want to do in the first place

Comment: Related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10998548/google-chart-extjs4-mvc-portalet-panel

Comment: Hello Hippo, I am unable to find the way to add YUI chart in Ext-js 4 I need some help to intigrate these charts.......Thanks

Comment: As said before try to make this a real question. You probably want to read this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) first.

Answer (score 0):

In order to render a YUI3 Chart into a Extjs 4 Panel, you need to render the Panel first and then render the Chart into the Panel's body. To do that you need to wait until the Ext Panel is rendered. Here's the basic idea:

```
YUI().use('charts', function (Y) {
  panel.on('render', function () {
    var chart = new Y.Chart({ render: panel.body.dom /* more options */ });
  });
});
```

As far as how to configure a YUI3 Chart, I can't do a better job than the YUI documentation and examples: http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/charts/